# Customising UITableView scrolling!

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Is it possible to make the table view allow scrolling only in one section and not others OR in other words allowing scrolling only in desired sections of the grouped table?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is entirely possible if you're willing to forego the use of a tableview. If you use a scrollview, you can achieve what you want by defining custom behaviour. It's not going to be easy but here are some suggestions:

1. Figure out how you want it laid out on the screen
2. Create a "floating cell" that will hang around, this will be your "not scrolling" section
3. With respect to #2 above, you'll have to figure out what kind of logic you want to make that floating cell disappear versus the other data.
4. The rest, you're effectively reimplementing a tableview.

Now, you can probably achieve this with a tableview, but it's be hairy big time.

Comment: What I basically want to do is to be able to get a view like flip side view of "Weather" & "Stocks" utility applications of iOS where first section has scrolling and in that section there's room for only a certain number of rows to be displayed to start with and scrolling allows to view more within the same rectangular area.

But thanks anyway mate!

Comment: weather and stocks are just using a table view that doesn't take up the whole page...